# Grafana rename query result

Tags: grafana

I am using Grafana to display logs from Elastic Stack. I have a requirement which involves renaming a column's values.
[image]

I need to rename the values of the `log.source.address` column such that to only keep the ip address.
For example, `172.29.42.31:45031` would become `172.29.42.31`.
I tried the "Rename by Regex" transformation with this regex `[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{5}` but then I found out that "Rename by Regex" renames the column names, not the values.
I could also truncate the last 6 characters from the right to get the result  I need.

Is there a way to do this directly in Grafana?

Answer (score 2):

On last version Grafana : go to Transform (near query in snapshoot) / and regex rename funtion